# Multiple Directives working together

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an idea I want to build in Angular but I'm not sure if it is possible and how I can start developing it.

The idea is that by extending html with some own attributes, I could call a webservice without any need for javascript code.

The result for the developer would be something like this:

```
<div service-url="http://myWebService" service-id="id1">
    <input service-id="id1" service-input-id="FirstParameter"/>
    <input service-id="id1" service-input-id="SecondParameter"/>
    <button service-id="id1" service-submit>Submit</button>
</div>
```

The idea is you can create a service call with a unique `service-id`. You can then create elements such as inputs/selects where you use the same `service-id` together with a unique `service-input-id` that refers to the field in the webservice the value should be mapped to. Finally by adding the `service-submit` attribute to an element a trigger can be created to call the webservice.

If I translate this to AngularJS, each of those custom attributes needs to be a custom directive if I'm not mistaking. But I'm not sure how I can let them work together when the scope is isolated. For example: when the user clicks  the button with the `service-submit`, I need to get all the values of the inputs that are linked to the same `service-id`.

I'm not even sure if I'm thinking in the right direction regarding how to approach this in Angular. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

*PS: My idea is not with webservices but it seemed like the closest thing I could use in my question to get the concept across.*

Comment: I think it should go, I would try to use a Service, which holds the Data and multiple directives one which uses the service call and writes the Data into the Service and other Directives which uses the service Data can show the right data in your Inputs and so on. - just an idea

Comment: You can also define a controller on the div and then declare a shared scope between controller and directives sharing a common object between them which would allow data to flow between them.

Comment: @TheRodeo I would not use scope any more in my directive or controller and least of all a shared scope. You create a hard coupling between the directive and controller. To share data between components the best way is to use a factory or better as service - so far I know

Comment: @squadwuschel thank you,that did the trick for me!

Comment: @squadwuschel It is as much of a hard coupling as service. The object that you are picking the values from changes is all i.e. scope or service. IMHO, service is supposed to be more of a way for getting the information out of a controller to an external component (controller or directive).